# I just started my journey in Javascript, am finding this array question bit tricky and confusing. Please someone should help me out here

Tags: javascript, arrays

```
const numbers = [1,2,3,4,5]
let luckyNum = numbers.pop()
```

What will be the value of numbers?

Hint: numbers is stored in a constant not a variable

Comment: Just run and look at the result.

Comment: What do you find confusing?  Have you tried running this code and seeing what happens?

Comment: numbers being a `const` rather than a `var` will not impact this particular code in any way.

Comment: From MDN: _Constants are block-scoped, much like variables defined using the let statement. The value of a constant cannot change through **reassignment**, and it can't be redeclared._ In you particular case `numbers` holds a reference to the array and that reference will remain constant, not the array itself.

Comment: @brad yes i have but it brought out an uncaught error

Answer (score -1):

From the [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const) you can read:

> Constants are block-scoped, much like variables defined using the let statement. **The value of a constant cannot change through reassignment**, and it can't be redeclared.

In you particular case the `numbers` variable holds a reference to the array and that reference will remain "constant", not the array itself. As you can check on next example:

```js
const numbers = [1,2,3,4,5];
let luckyNum = numbers.pop();
console.log("luckyNum:", luckyNum, "numbers:", numbers);

// Now, next line will trhow an error, because we are
// trying to do a reassingment on a const variable:
numbers = [];
```

In the particular case you are interested, you can use [Object.freeze()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/freeze) to prohibit changes on an `array` of primitives values:

```js
const numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
Object.freeze(numbers);

// Now, next line will thrown an error.
let luckyNum = numbers.pop();
console.log("luckyNum:", luckyNum, "numbers:", numbers);
```

I Hope this clarifies your doubts.

Comment: I will try these out thanks

Comment: @Henree_01 Ok, tell me when you have understood the concept. So I can delete the answer. People dislike answers on question that do not show efforts (keep this in mind next time), but I felt like helping you anyway.

Answer (score -1):

Even though it's a const, it will be modified and the new value will be [1,2,3,4].